# CollectionView scrolling changes the selected cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

CollectionView scrolling changes the selected cells. For example, there are 26 letters in my collectionView, items[0] is A, items[1] is B, ... items[25] is Z, now I selected items[1], it is B, and when I scroll the collectionView, items[1] will become deselected and there is another item will be selected. I know the problem is caused by Reuse but I don't know how to fix it properly even I use some solution that showed in google or StackOverflow.

My viewDidLoad:

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

My CollectionViewCell Class:

```
import UIKit
class AddCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
}
```

My CollectionView Setting:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return iconSet.count
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "iconCell", for: indexPath) as! IconCollectionViewCell
        cell.iconImage.image = UIImage(named:iconSet[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }
```

My CollectionView's didSelecteItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.3)
            cell.backgroundView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        }
```

My CollectionView's didDeSelecteItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.0)
            cell.backgroundView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to set the proper color in `cellForItemAt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by either store all selected item's index in separate array or you can manage separate property like `isSelected` in dictionary or array of custom class's objects whichever you used to fill your collectionview cells.

You can simply use array like below:
var arrIndex : [Int] = Int

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "iconCell", for: indexPath) as! IconCollectionViewCell
        cell.iconImage.image = UIImage(named:iconSet[indexPath.row])

         if arrIndex.contains(indexPath.item) {
               cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.3)

          }
          else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.0)

          }
        return cell

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     if !arrIndex.contains(indexPath.item) {
        arrIndex.append(indexPath.item)
        collectionview.reloadData()

     }
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if arrIndex.contains(indexPath.item) {
            arrIndex = arrIndex.filter { $0 != indexPath.item }
            collectionview.reloadData()
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Dhaval D! Thanks your answer! It is works! Thank you very much! But Why I already set "multiselection = fault", but it still can be multiselected? I try to modify the "didDeselectItemAt" but it doesn't work...

Comment: Oh! I just figured it out! In didSelectItemAt I add this "arrIndex.removeAll()" before "arrIndex.append(indexPath.item)"

Comment: I've been facing a similar issue for 3 days now and finally manage to fix it with this answer. Just had to adjust something, changed the code from the didDeselect to an else condition on didSelect. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 var selectedIndex = 0  // set default or nil and check it's nullability before usage
```

//

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "iconCell", for: indexPath) as! IconCollectionViewCell
        cell.iconImage.image = UIImage(named:iconSet[indexPath.row])

         if indexPath.row == selectedIndex {
               cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.3)

          }
          else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.0)

          }
        return cell

    }
```

My CollectionView's didSelecteItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      selectedIndex = indexPath.row
      collectionview.reloadData()
 }
```

My CollectionView's didDeSelecteItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // remove this
    }
```